# Appending div from another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 menu buttons which supposed to append divs from an external html.
Now I have this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:test2();" value="#CS" >CS</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:test2();" value="#PS" >PS</a></li>
</ul>
```

And 2 divs on the external html, that just have simple text in them saying "text1" and "text2".

I use this code to append the data:

```
$.get('external/list.html', function (data) {
        $(data).filter('#PS').appendTo('#content')
});
```

How can I "upgrade" it to take for example an attribute like value, and use it to choose what div to append? Because I prefer to have it as 1 function instead of making 2.

Also this code appends a div, but it doesn't reset it. It just keeps spamming the same div over and over and over. How can I stop it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**

Keep a single call to your `$.get`, as you are doing now, but pass reference of your clicked `element` through your `function` as below:

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:test2(this);" value="#CS" >CS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" onclick="javascript:test2(this);" value="#PS" >PS</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
function test2(ctrl)
{
    var element=$(ctrl).attr('value');
    $.get('external/list.html', function (data) {
```

<strike>$(data).filter(element).appendTo('#content');</strike>

```
         //element will have value either #PS or #CS
    });
}
```

> **Note - [`.appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendto/) will keep on appending the data to your `DOM`, instead use [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) which replaces contents everytime**

**Ex:**

```
$(data).filter(element).html('#content');
```

---

**Option 2**

You can also attach `click` event to your `a` tags with a common class given for both thus removing inline `function` call as below:

```
<ul>
     <li><a href="#" value="#CS" class="menu">CS</a></li>
     <li><a href="#" value="#PS" class="menu">PS</a></li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
$(".menu").on('click',function(){
    var element=$(this).attr('value'); //this refers to clicked element
    $.get('external/list.html', function (data) {
```

<strike>$(data).filter(element).appendTo('#content');</strike>

```
         //element will have value either #PS or #CS
    });
});
```

---

**Update**

Ideally `html` should work but I imposed it in wrong way. You just need to change one thing as below:

```
$("#content").html($(data).filter(element));
```

Comment: for some reason it doesnt work. maybe i missed something? i didnt see you added a second option hehe  in the first option in the element var what is "ctrl"?

Comment: it just says that "ctrl" is undefined

Comment: yea i dunno maybe its problem with chrome ill test it on other browsers

Comment: Here is a **[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/L4L9k98b/)** with `function` and here is a **[`DEMO`](https://jsfiddle.net/L4L9k98b/1/)** with click event..

Comment: oh my mistake sorry it works lol instead of ctrl i had ctrll both of the options work great but 1st option posts 1 input of CS and PS without reseting (i need to switch between them) and the 2nd option posts input+1 at every click

Comment: option 1: .html didnt work so i changed to appendTO(#content) it started working but it appends the div every click and i need it to append the div once every click and if the div exists already then just refresh it Option 2: every click on either button posts additional div text first click 1 text line second click adittional 2 text lines and so on :P

Comment: @Decapitar Sorry.. It was my mistake.. Please find the updated answer at the end of the answer.. :)

Comment: Cool.. Now if it helped you please upvote and mark it as answer.. ;) Anyways.. Happy Coding.. :)